# Totals row in Toad resultset? (via UI)

Tags: oracle, toad, summarization

*In Toad for Oracle 12:*

I make various queries on-the-fly to analyze data. For example:

```
select
    worktype,
    count(*) as count
from
    maximo.workorder
group by
    worktype
```

[image]

---

In the query resultset, it would be helpful if I could toggle a *totals* row on/off to quickly analyze the results.

Example: get the grand total of the COUNT column. Or, in other queries, play around with count, max, standard deviation, variance, etc.

---

It would be the equivalent to the [MS Access totals tool](https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/microsoft_access_2016/howto/how_to_create_a_totals_row_in_access_2016.cfm) (not to be confused with GROUP BY):

[image]

---

Is there an way to do that using the UI in Toad 12?

Comment: Not that I've ever seen. Toad isn't really a reporting tool; it's primary function is as an IDE for PL/SQL, or (for many) as a database admin tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, I believe. I don't have TOAD 12 any more, but - give it a try:

- select all cells you're interested in
- right-click
- from the menu, select "Calculate selected cells"
- check the result

  - note that - if result list contains a lot of columns and you're *calculating* the ones far on the right, you'll have to scroll left to see the result

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, what tool did you use to add number labels to the screenshots?

Comment: You're welcome. It was PicPick (https://picpick.app/en/)